# How to set default catalog configuration/script when start up flink sql-gateway.sh

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I can't find any documentation that specified default configuration from [sql-gateway](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/sql-gateway/overview/)
. I am wondering where can I set the default catalog when accessing `https://amazon.flinksqlgateway:8083/v1/session`